# Android Studio IDE error

Tags: android

I have a problem and I can not see the configuration panels to create a new activity, I hope you can help, thank you very much. here's a photo

[image: Photo error]

Comment: Maybe you can try the new Android Studio 2.0

Comment: A new version? I did not know it

Comment: Check update and set channel to canary

Comment: Yes, I upgraded to the 2.0 thank you very much

Comment: But android studio 2.0 has some bugs too!

Comment: But I guess Android Studio 2.0 is much better than the other

Comment: Yes,it's faster and has new feature.

Comment: You recommend leaving the 2.0 or install another outdated version?

Comment: I keep 2.0 and 1.5.If 2.0 get error I can't slove , I'm back to 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved, what I did was reduce a little the size of the edit box from the sides and automatically design appeared. Thank you very much to all